# jQuery UI Draggable and Droppable: Call a function when all draggable elements on the page are dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am having some trouble figuring out how to call a function after all draggable elements are dropped. I have two side-by-side columns. The list on the right contains 8 elements that are dropped to the left column, also with 8 elements (a matching game). I can call a function, (alert("drop")) in the code below, when each item is dropped, but how do I call a function after all the elements on the page have been dropped? Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
    snap: ".snapTarget",
    snapMode: "inner",
    snapTolerance: 15,
    revert: "invalid"
    });

    $(".word1 .wordBg").draggable({
    snapTolerance: 15,
    revert: "invalid"
    });
    $(".word1").droppable({
    accept: ".word1",
    drop: function(){
    alert("drop");
   }
   });
  .... word2 . . .
  .... word8 
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: you could use a global variable to keep the count. `count++; if(count===8) callMyFunction();` in drop function.

Comment: Need to see the HTML but you could on load (of the page) count how many item are in the first column then on each drop (in into the second, where currently you have your alert) count how many items are in the second, if the second column count equals the initial first column count then everything is moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to gp and silver in the comments above, here is the working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".kaminari_match_pagination").hide()
var dropCount = 0;
var wordCount = $('.word').length / 2;

$(function() {
$(".draggable").draggable({
  snap: ".snapTarget",
  snapMode: "inner",
  snapTolerance: 15,
  revert: "invalid"
  });

$(".word1 .wordBg").draggable({
  snapTolerance: 15,
  revert: "invalid"
  });
$(".word1").droppable({
  accept: ".word1",
  drop: function(){
  dropCount++;
    if (dropCount === wordCount) {
      $(".kaminari_match_pagination").show();
 }
 });
 .... word2 . . .
 .... word8 
});
</script>
```